# Prove that two norms are equivalents

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces, proof-verification

> 1. Two norms $\|\bullet\|_1$ and $\|\bullet\|_2$ are **equivalents** iff  $\;\exists\;c_1,c_2>0$ such that $c_1\|x\|_1\le \|x\|_2\le c_2\|x\|_1$

We're working in $\mathcal C^1[0,1]$, and I have the following norms: $$\|f\|_{1,\infty}:=\|f\|_{\infty}+\|f'\|_{\infty}=\max\{|f(x)|: 0\le x\le 1\}+\max\{|f'(x)|: 0\le x\le 1\}$$
and $$|||f|||_2:=|f(0)|+\|f'\|_{\infty}=|f(0)|+\max\{|f'(x)|: 0\le x\le 1\}$$

After a few drafts I've come to the conclusion that I have to two consider cases. If $f\equiv c$ and $f\not \equiv c$, where $c\in \Bbb R$ is a constant.

For the second case: because of its definition we have that $|f(0)|\le \|f'\|_{\infty}$, then is always true that: $$1\le \frac {\|f\|_{1,\infty}}{|||f|||_2}$$ 
then we can consider $1\le c_2$ (see definition *upstairs*), so: $$1\le c_2\le c_2 \frac {\|f\|_{1,\infty}}{|||f|||_2}$$
We want: $$c_1 |||f|||_2 \le \|f\|_{1,\infty}\Rightarrow c_1 \frac {|||f|||_2}{\|f\|_{1,\infty}}\le 1$$
so we just have to take $c_1=\frac 1{c_2}$ wich is always non-negative.

Now, I separate the case when $f\equiv c$ because in that case happens that: $\|f\|_{1,\infty}=0 \Leftrightarrow f\equiv c$ and $|||f|||_2\Leftrightarrow f\equiv 0 $, but from here, I don't know what to do to include this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have observed, $||f||_{2}\le||f||_{1}$ for every $f$ in $C^{1}[0,1]$; so you can take $c_2=1$.

If $f$ in $C^{1}[0,1]$ has its maximum at 0, then $||f||_{\infty}=|f(0)|$.

Otherwise, if f has its maximum at $x\in(0,1]$, then $f(x)=f^{\prime}(c)x+f(0)$ for some $c\in(0,x)$ by the Mean Value Theorem; so $||f||_{\infty}=|f^{\prime}(c)x+f(0)|\le|f^{\prime}(c)||x|+|f(0)|\le||f^{\prime}||_{\infty}+|f(0)|$.

Now you can use this to find a constant $k$ which satisfies

$||f||_{1}=||f||_{\infty}+||f^{\prime}||_{\infty}\le k(|f(0)|+||f^{\prime}||_{\infty})=k||f||_{2}$, and then let $c_1=\frac{1}{k}$.

Comment: This is great! thank you very much! I just have a technical question, how did you came up with this?

Comment: I realized that I needed to relate $||f||_{\infty}$ to $||f^{\prime}||_{\infty}$, so the Mean Value Theorem seemed like a good way to relate them.